# Problems when downloading .csv files from Google insight for search using Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to use **perl** to download .csv files from **google insights for search**. But I meet with two problems:

1. It seems that the download URL is a redirect one, so I cannot download it with LWP module.
   The url is 
   "*http://www.google.com/insights/search/overviewReport?q=dizzy&date=1%2F2012%205m&cmpt=date&content=1&export=1*". You may try it, probably should login first.
2. It seems that I have to store the session before downloading. Without doing this, I will get a warn - like "reach the quota limit".

How can I download this .csv file automatically using **PERL**? Thanks for the help.

Here is my code:

```
#create userAgent object
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("MyApp/0.1 ");

#create a request
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://www.google.com/insights/search/overviewReport?q=dizzy&date=1%2F2012%205m&cmpt=date&content=1&export=1');

my $res = $ua->request($req);

#check the outcome of the response
if($res->is_success) {
    print $res->content;
}
else {
    print $res->status_line, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm highly recommend you to use WWW::Mechanize for web automation (this is high level LWP::UserAgent):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->agent_alias("Windows IE 6");

$mech->get("https://accounts.google.com/serviceLogin");
$mech->submit_form(

    form_id => "gaia_loginform",
    fields => {

        Email => 'gangabass@gmail.com',
        Passwd => 'password',
    },
    button => "signIn",
);

$mech->get("http://www.google.com/insights/search/overviewReport?q=dizzy&date=1%2F2012%205m&cmpt=date&content=1&export=1");
open my $fh, ">:encoding(utf8)", "report.csv" or die $!;
print {$fh} $mech->content();
close $fh;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! I will see the perl documentation.

Comment: There is one more question. You save the $mech->content() into the file, but why the data I need is in $mech->content()? I mean, the url is not a downloading link which can give you the .csv file directly, is it a redirecting one? What does it send you back?

Comment: You just gives `$mech` a link and it will process all redirects for you.